# MPMoviePlayerViewController lock screen playback controls not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, playback

I have an app that has the following setup:

**URMoviePlayerViewController extends MPMoviePlayerViewController**

- has the method remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event implemented, as well as:

  ```
  (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];    
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
      [self becomeFirstResponder];
  }

  (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
  {
      return YES;
  }
  ```

**URPlayerViewController has the URMoviePlayerViewController as a property**

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) URMoviePlayerViewController *player;
```

- player is initialized when a call to play a clip of audio is made; if it is already initialized, it does not re-initialize the player
- URPlayerViewController has a view that is a custom player with play/pause, next/previous controls that is initialized and added to the subview in the viewDidLoad method

**URAppDelegate has URPlayerViewController as a property**

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) URPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
```

- playerViewController is initialized in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
- playerViewController's view is added to the *window* - so that the custom player is visible throughout the app

**Problem:**

Everything usually works well. Every now and then on the lock screen the playback controls (play/pause/next/previous) stop working. remoteControlReceivedWithEvent never gets called. I have not been able to reproduce this consistently.

Any advice or ideas on debugging this issue around playback would be great as I am not able to consistently reproduce this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing below methods, just add it in your existing code and accept the answer if it will work:

Remove beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents from viewdidload and put it in viewdidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

}

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self resignFirstResponder];
```

}

Comment: I had tried this change earlier (however I used viewDidDisappear instead of viewWillDisappear). Still no luck. I still see the playback controls stop working once in a while.